# MySQL: Sum count of a group and join the result?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

In MySQL I would like to combine table rows from a coupons, targets, and visits table. The way they relate is that 1 coupon can only have 1 target. A target is a url and some other display settings. one target can have many visits.

```
// coupons
couponId
couponName

// targets
targetId
url
fk_coupons_targets // foreign key    

// visits
visitId
urlVisited
fk_targets_visits // foreign key
```

A count should be done based on rows of matching visits.urlVisited to tally how many visits a given target.url received.

The intended query should have a record that can eventually output into a table like this:

```
couponId: 1 
targetUrl: example.com/page1 
number of visits: 3
```

At the moment I'm not sure if this needs both a "summing" query and "joining" query or if they can or should be done together. Here's what I have so far.

```
// select every visit record and group a numeric count of 
// records by same url value (in visits table)

select count(*) from visits 
group by urlVisited;



// left join all coupon ids by matching foreign key in target 
// table. Then inner join all summed visits by matching url in
// targets table

select * from coupons c
left join targets t on t.fk_targets_coupons = c.couponId
inner join visits v on v.urlVisited = t.url;
```

I'm unclear on how to connect the sum value. My 2nd query just looks like it will ignore the sum and just return a bunch of matching rows in visits which is not desired. How should this query actually be written?

Comment: Pls describe the foreign key links between the tables. Which field in targets table corresponds to couponId field in coupon table?. Also which field is connecting the visits are target tables

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
select c.couponId,t.url,count(v.visitId) 
from coupons c
join targets t on c.couponId=t.fk_coupons_targets
join visits v on t.url=v.urlVisited
group by c.couponId;
```

Comment: If it's fails,try adding more info about your table structure and sample data.